# While trying to get committed offset I get: Error computing size for field 'coordinator_key'

Tags: apache-kafka

I get org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.SchemaException: Error computing size for field 'coordinator_key': Missing value for field 'coordinator_key' which has no default value.

Call looks like:

```
OffsetAndMetadata offsetInfo = consumer.committed(partition);
```

Broker version: 0.11.0.2
Using Java client: org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:1.0.0

BTW:

```
Map<TopicPartition, Long> endOffsets = consumer.endOffsets(topicPartitions)
```

works fine.

(end goal is to get the topic total lag in code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't set the group.id in the properties while constructing the DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory, the group id is probably used as the coordinator_key for the query, the error message was not much helpful...